# Is it possible to decompose an image into basis images using MATLAB?

Tags: image-processing, matlab, fft, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum

I have read that:

> Using Fourier decomposition any arbitrary image can be represented as
>   summation of orthogonal basis images.

I want to see the basis images for any image say Lena or Cameraman, etc.

So can anybody help me to decompose an image into basis images and reconstruct back the same image from basis images using MATLAB?

Comment: Related: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1637/what-does-frequency-domain-denote-in-case-of-images/1644#1644 (That's what the "basis images" look like)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't make any difference what image you choose. The basis images are the same. When decomposing a given image into basis images we find the coefficients only and define the given image as a weighted sum of all those basis images.

In the following, you can see the basis images based on 2D DFT of size $8$ ($64$ basis images in total)

[image]

Note the different 2-D frequencies. Any given $8\times8$ image is a weighted sum of these 64 images.